# Hibernate session and transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I was trying to figure out how hibernate works and few things are there I want to how they works and I wanted to know if I understood correctly.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory();
```

The above does following things

1. Creates entitymanager factory instance.
2. EntityManagerFactory stores the mapping for all the entity classes.
3. Its the provider of entity manager instances.

what else above line does?

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()
```

1. createa an entitymanager.
2. EntityManager is responsible for managing lifecycle of managed objects.

what else above line do? does it create a session with database?

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
```

1. Does above lines creates a database session?
2. is session and transaction and session are java side things or database side things?
3. what transaction and session means ?

   `em.getTransaction().commit();`
4. I feel that this line does all the work of creating transaction and saving the data to the database. am I correct?

   `em.close();`
5. this line closes the database session.

   `emf.close();`
6. all the mapping present in the factory are lost and eligible for GC?

Am I correct with my understandings?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction